# Use this outside of constructor

Tags: c++, qt

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, GraphicalUI *graphicalUI) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);



    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Label", this);
    label->setPixmap(graphicalUI->textures["background"]);
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");

}

void buildWindow(Level *level, GraphicalUI *graphicUI) {
    QGridLayout layout = QGridLayout(this);
    
}
```

The problem here is found in the buildWindow() function. Obviously I cannot just use
`QGridLayout(this)`. But I want the MainWindow to be the parent of my QGridLayout.
How do I do this? Also, the buildWindow function is going to be called **externally**.

Comment: You might have meant `QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(this);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Still I get an invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function

Comment: `buildWindow` looks to be a free function. Should that not be `MainWindow::buildWindow` or something similar?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, I'm onto that but I always get an out of-line definition of 'buildWindow' does not match any declaration in 'MainWindow'. Even though its declared correctly in the .h

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: That's the problem you should be resolving then. My usual trick is to paste `void buildWindow(Level *level, GraphicalUI *graphicUI)` right below the declaration of `buildWindow` in the class and see what the difference is. If you don't see it, post the definition here and see if we can pick it off for you. Bonus points for making a [mre].

Comment: *"Obviously"* -- a word often used to mean "I hope something is true, but I have no idea why so please don't pressure me to reveal my ignorance". Better would be to use the question to explain *why* you think the thing is true. In this case, would that reason be "because `buildWindow` is not a member function"? If so, you probably should also add an explanation of why it is not a member function and/or of why the parent has to be `this` instead of a different pointer to the intended parent.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is an implicit argument to all member functions. Which means it is available in all member functions not just the constructor. It's just a pointer to the current object.

Since the `buildWindow` function is not a member function of `MainWindow`(which I do not recommend) you can pass the address of the `MainWindow` instance to `buildWindow` function. By default `MainWindow` is instantiated in the `main.cpp` file when you create a new GUI project in Qt Creator.
like:

```
void buildWindow(Level *level, GraphicalUI *graphicUI, MainWindow* window) {
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(window);  
}
```

But:

In your code:

```
void buildWindow(Level *level, GraphicalUI *graphicUI) {
    QGridLayout layout = QGridLayout(this);  
}
```

variable layout is a local variable in the scope of this function. When your code reaches the end of function (closing brackets), your QGridLayout layout object is destroyed. In order to avoid this, you should use pointers and the `new` keyword.

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
```

now leyout is just a pointer to a QGridLayout object. This object is destroyed if you call `delete layout;` manually or the parent object (in this case your mainwindow object) get's destroyed.
But now the problem is you can't access this QGridLayout later on from other functions because the pointer `layout` will be lost at the end of this function. I recommend using a class member variable like:

```
private:
    QGridLayout *layout;
```

in your header file and initialize if inside your function like:

```
void MainWindow::buildWindow(Level *level, GraphicalUI *graphicUI) {
    layout = new QGridLayout(this);  
}
```

Make sure you don't use the layout pointer before calling this function.

Comment: The question asks how to use `this` in a non-member function. You did not address this at all. In fact, you made the situation worse by trying to access the data member `layout` in a non-member function. Sorry, but no matter how good your information is, if it does not address the question, then it is not a good answer.

Comment: *"should use pointers and the `new` keyword."* -- This advice could be better. Good uses of `new` have declined over the years, and now there are often better alternatives to using `new`. In this case, better advice would be to use *smart* pointers and `std::make_unique`. The one common-ish scenario I can think of where `new` is still sometimes a good option is when initializing a `shared_ptr` that will have associated `weak_ptr`s.

Comment: Your're right about STL  but in Qt you don't use STL smart pointers at all. Qt has it's own smart pointer classes and you DO  use `new`in Qt because of the parent system. You pass the parent object as the argument of the constructor, then when the parent object is deleted your object will be deleted too. No worries about memory management when using QObjects and parent system.  That's what he is doing here and `this` can be replaced by any pointer to a QObject instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
void MainWindow::buildWindow(Level *level, GraphicalUI *graphicUI) {
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(this);
}
```

Thats the solution.
The function is also **required** to exist in the header of the class.

Comment: I'd remove the bit about the header because it begs the questions "What header?" and "What adjustments?"

Comment: What header? There is no header mentioned in the question. Are you suggesting that the person who wrote the question left out important details? Maybe you could talk that person into including all relevant details in the question? :)

Comment: Is `class MainWindow` an application defined class declared in the application? Or  is it a class that is defined by Qt? In the latter case it will be difficult to add the static member function.